# Does Magento cache third party modules?

Tags: magento

Does Magento cache third party folder and files?
I have some WordPress blogs in the Magento root folder, will Magento attempt to cache them?
If it is possible how can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 9):

No.

Magentos caching is object based, not folder based.

To see how Magento implemented its major caches see the classes:

```
Mage_Core_Model_Config                            // CONFIG
Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update                     // LAYOUT_GENERAL_CACHE_TAG
Mage_Core_Block_Abstract                          // BLOCK_HTML
Mage_Core_Model_Translate                         // TRANSLATE
Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract   // COLLECTION_DATA
Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute                   // EAV_ATTRIBUTE
Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Processor              // FPC
```

Answer (score 1):

No, as it's not part of Magento.

Answer (score 0):

its odd that we need to type at least 30 chars to say "no, it will not cache them"